# Can a university in Vietnam use COVID-19 to force students to reveal personal information?

Tags: privacy, covid-19

Asking for a friend, assume "I" is said friend.

I'm a student of a university in Vietnam. My university has sent out an email to all students to fill out a Google spreadsheet, which is open and can be edited by any other student, if they're staying in a certain area. I've asked them to use Google Forms instead  to protect the students but they're insisting that I fill out said form or else they're going to report my non-compliance to the police.

The form includes the full name (though we have student IDs), phone number and permanent address. This is said in the email to be "an emergency notice policy from the government".

I really don't want to reveal my phone number or address to others. Can we legally decline and offer to provide the required information in another way?